# Managing Multiple Wordpress Sites

Tags: wordpress

Not sure if this is the right place to ask, sorry if its not. I build a lot of Wordpress sites. My problem is, the number of them is getting big and harder to update them all when new releases come out.

I have written an app that will download the latest Wordpress release, and manually ftp the new files to all the clients, but this takes forever... need a new way.

I wanted to restructure this while I can or start a new process at least. Whats the best way to manage multiple Wordpress sites and keep them all updated? Some people have said 1 DB and modded config, others I have seen said to keep all installs separate and use plugins to automatically upgrade, but I don't know whats best to do. Ideas? Thanks :)

Comment: As an update to this question, Wordpress now [automatically updates](https://codex.wordpress.org/Updating_WordPress#Automatic_Background_Updates) as of 3.7.1+

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If these were all sites you managed on your own server, I'd recommend using a [Multisite](http://codex.wordpress.org/Create_A_Network) installation rather than separate instances of WordPress.  This way you only have one set of themes, one set of plug-ins, and one copy of WordPress to maintain.

If these sites are on different servers (i.e. you're maintaining sites for clients remotely), I'd recommend you look in to a beta account with [WP Remote](http://www.wpremote.com/).  This is a service specifically built to allow you to remotely monitor and update multiple WordPress installations.  It might be the best solution for you because it allows you to use the one-click update rather than manually downloading/FTP-ing the new files.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this free self hosted app http://infinitewp.com
No limitation in number of sites being managed. You can update WP/plugin/themes, do backups, one click login to your WordPress admin panel.

Answer (score 0):

EAMann is right, especially with the new Multi Site features in Wordpress 3.0, there is no better way to manage multiple sites under one umbrella. Being a developer myself, I know the pain of having to login to all those different accounts!

The way to set it up is create a "master domain name" that you will log into. Place this in your WP Config:

`define('WP_ALLOW_MULTISITE', true);`

Then login to your admin panel, navigate to TOOLS>Network.

After you've set everything up, copy/paste what it tells you to your HTAccess and WP Config file.

The next step, especially if you are putting clients on this network, is they will want their own domain name, not AIBot.com/theirname right? Thats where Domain Mapping comes in:

http://ottopress.com/2010/wordpress-3-0-multisite-domain-mapping-tutorial/

Check that out and good luck!

Answer (score 0):

What you need is [www.managewp.com](http://www.managewp.com) it can do all of that for you plus a ton of other excellent features.